# PowerShell The term is not recognized as cmdlet function script file or operable program

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0, command-prompt

I am implementing a script in powershell and getting the below error. The sceen shot is there exactly what I entered and the resulting error.

[image]

At this path there is file `Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1` which I got from [Technet Gallery](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71). I am following the steps from it, though there are errors.

Comment: The screenshot is not working

Comment: Related post - [Error: The term './RunCommandLine.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32507107/465053)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You first have to 'dot' source the script, so for you :

```
. .\Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1
```

The first 'dot' asks PowerShell to load the script file into your PowerShell environment, not to start it. You should also use `set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` or `set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned` see([the Execution Policy instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh847748.aspx)).

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of searchers, there is another way you can produce this error message - by missing the $ off the script block name when calling it.

e.g. I had a script block like so:

```
$qa = {
    param($question, $answer)
    Write-Host "Question = $question, Answer = $answer"
}
```

I tried calling it using:

```
&qa -question "Do you like powershell?" -answer "Yes!"
```

But that errored. The correct way was:

```
&$qa -question "Do you like powershell?" -answer "Yes!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way this error message can occur.

If PowerShell is open in a directory other than the target file, *e.g.*:

If `someScript.ps1` is located here: `C:\SlowLearner\some_missing_path\someScript.ps1`, then `C:\SlowLearner>. ./someScript.ps1` wont work.

In that case, *navigate to the path:* `cd some_missing_path` then this would work:

`C:\SlowLearner\some_missing_path>. ./someScript.ps1`

Comment: Well, yes, because in a path, `.` means "the current directory". If you are not trying to use something in the current directory, then `.` would be an invalid path. You don't need to switch directories so that `.` works, just specify an actual valid path: `. C:\SlowLearner\some_missing_path\someScript.ps1`

Comment: @AndrewF - indeed. The intent was merely to shine a light on how such an error might be produced.