# The term '' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, deployment

When I try to check `netlify` is install or not then show me this error:

```
 : The term '' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\alami\AppData\Roaming\npm\netlify.ps1:1 char:1
+  ...
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**After successfully install `npm i -g netlify-cli` then I get this error**
[image]

I have tried to fixed this problem

**Any suggestion please**

Comment: please read from here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156451/powershell-the-term-is-not-recognized-as-cmdlet-function-script-file-or-operable)
hope your problem will be solved